# maxscale: Backend server didn't accept authentication for user

Tags: linux, database, high-availability, maxscale

on the same machine where maxscale installed, connection is successfull but when running any query it shows

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

logs shows this message:

```
maxscale[]: Backend server didn't accept authentication for user
```

i already set the follwoing in /etc/maxscale.cnf:

```
[Splitter Service]
enable_root_user=1
localhost_match_wildcard_host=1
```

the OS is Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
maxscale version is 2.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens is when the user has grants on the client host but not on the Maxscale host or the grants are not the same.

#### How to check that my user grants match?

To see which user grant you are using, execute the following SQL from both the MaxScale host and the client host.

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
```

This will return the user that your client connection is using to connect to MaxScale and the user that MaxScale uses to connect to the database itself.

The next step is to check that the grants for both users are similar by executing the following SQL.

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

MaxScale has [a helper script](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/MaxScale/blob/2.1/script/create_grants) that can be used to show what users and grants need to be created.